# Using Xuggler to detect Webcam with Java

Tags: java, ffmpeg, log4j, webcam, xuggler

I'm trying to use **[Xuggler](http://www.xuggle.com/downloads)** library to handle webcam video stream in Java.
My project contains these files:

- **Xuggler Jar** ([xuggle-xuggler-5.4.jar](http://xuggle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/repo/share/java/xuggle/xuggle-xuggler/5.4/))
- **SLF4J Jars** (required by Xuggler and downloadable [here](http://www.slf4j.org/download.html)):

  - jcl-over-slf4j-1.6.4.jar
  - jul-to-slf4j-1.6.4.jar
  - log4j-over-slf4j-1.6.4.jar
  - slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar
  - slf4j-ext-1.6.4.jar
  - slf4j-migrator-1.6.4.jar
  - slf4j-simple-1.6.4.jar
- [**DisplayWebcamVideo.java**](http://xuggle.googlecode.com/svn-history/r674/trunk/java/xuggle-xuggler/src/com/xuggle/mediatool/demos/DisplayWebcamVideo.java) as main class

I run the main method using `"vfwcap"` and `"0"` as arguments.
Application starts correctly, i can see myself from the webcam but **it's just the first frame**: the stream freezes and i see this output:

`5022 [Thread-3] ERROR org.ffmpeg - [vfwcap @ 000000000039A320] real-time buffer 75% full! frame dropped!`

`5622 [Thread-3] ERROR org.ffmpeg - [vfwcap @ 000000000039A320] real-time buffer 85% full! frame dropped!`

`6522 [Thread-3] ERROR org.ffmpeg - [vfwcap @ 000000000039A320] real-time buffer 95% full! frame dropped!`

`6822 [Thread-3] ERROR org.ffmpeg - [vfwcap @ 000000000039A320] real-time buffer 101% full! frame dropped!`

`6822 [Thread-3] ERROR org.ffmpeg - [vfwcap @ 000000000039A320] real-time buffer 101% full! frame dropped!`
What's the problem here? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved by using [this](https://github.com/xuggle/xuggle-xuggler/blob/master/src/com/xuggle/xuggler/demos/DisplayWebcamVideo.java) as Main class**